# Glossaries: Single key to both acronym and symbol entries

Tags: glossaries, glossaries-extra

I am creating a document where I'd like to have a glossary of terms, a list of acronyms and a list of symbols. Some glossary entries combine several, e.g. BSDF stands for "bidirectional distribution function", can have some definition in the glossary and is represented as `$f$` in equations.

So far, I put together this MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[acronym,symbols]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

% define entry in 'main' glossary:
\newglossaryentry{bsdf}{name={bidirectional scattering distribution function},
description={Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua}
}

% define entry in 'acronym' glossary:
\newacronym{acr:bsdf}{BSDF}{bidirectional scattering distribution function}

% define entry in 'symbols' glossary:
\newglossaryentry{sym:bsdf}{
  name={\ensuremath{f}},
  description={\acrfull{acr:bsdf}},
  type=symbols
}

\begin{document}
A sample document with a \gls{bsdf} (\acrshort{acr:bsdf}) and its symbol \gls{sym:bsdf}.

\printglossary[type=main]
\printglossary[type=acronym]
\printglossary[type=symbols]
\end{document}
```

I still have a different label for the term, acronym and symbol, which is inconvenient. Actually, in addition to having a single key to print the name, acronym and symbol, the best would be to have a single glossary entry, which I could then filter to print my glossaries.

Something like:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[<some options>]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{bsdf}{name={bidirectional scattering distribution function},
description={Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua},
acronym={BSDF},
symbol={\ensuremath{f}}
}

\begin{document}
A sample document with a \gls{bsdf} (\glsacronym{bsdf}) and its symbol \glssymbol{bsdf}.

\printglossary[type=terms]
\printglossary[type=acronyms]
\printglossary[type=symbols]
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: Do you want the entry to appear in all glossaries even if it has only been used in one form? That is, should `bsdf` appear in the `symbols` glossary, even if the symbol has never been used, only the abbreviation?

Comment: Also, do you need `glossaries`' capability to automatically switch between short and long forms of abbreviations?

Comment: I'd like all three (glossary entry, acronym and symbol) to appear in their respective glossary. In this specific case, a defined entry means that it is used somewhere in the document.

Comment: And I do not need the ability to switch between short and long abbreviation forms, manual control is fine.

Comment: I've looked into this a bit. It is easy enough to create a combined glossary entry for all three use cases, the hard part is filtering the entries when printing the glossary. We would have to let `glossaries` create _one_ glossary containing all the entries and then use glossary styles to filter which ones to print in which glossary. Wen then start to fight the nicely prepared glossary and I don't think the hackery necessary to get this working is worth the trouble.

Comment: I would say it's better to create your own front end that manages three distinct glossaries, similar to [Denys' suggestion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/495745/48973). This way you don't lose all the advantages that `glossaries` is offering. For example, you could have the entries sorted differently in the different glossaries, which might be useful.

Comment: That's true indeed. I can also set up some conditionals in the entry definition macro to skip glossary entry creation when empty arguments are found, which turns out to be useful for my use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you just can define commands, one for creating three glossary entries, and two for showing them without prefix?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[acronym,symbols]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

% create 3 entries at once
\newcommand{\myglossaryentry}[5]{%
\newglossaryentry{#1}{name={#3},description={#4}}%
\newacronym{acr:#1}{#2}{#3}%
\newglossaryentry{sym:#1}{name={#5}, description={#3}, type=symbols}%
}

% short commands
\newcommand{\glsacronym}[1]{\acrshort{acr:#1}}
\newcommand{\glssym}[1]{\gls{sym:#1}}

\myglossaryentry{bsdf}{BSDF}{bidirectional scattering distribution function}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua}{\ensuremath{f}}

\begin{document}
A sample document with a \gls{bsdf} (\acrshort{acr:bsdf}) and its symbol \gls{sym:bsdf}.
A sample document with a \gls{bsdf} (\glsacronym{bsdf}) and its symbol \glssym{bsdf}.

\printglossary[type=main]
\printglossary[type=acronym]
\printglossary[type=symbols]
\end{document}
```